# How to type a plain object function param using generics and ternary operators in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is a simplified version (below) of a requirement that involves a generic type that accepts either a union of strings or a plain object. If a union of strings is provided, those strings become object keys, each with the same value. If a plain object is provided, then that same object becomes the type.

This works when assigning the type to a variable (see `obj` below) but not when assiging the type to a function param (see `fn` below).

What am I doing wrong?

```
type Test<K extends string | {}> = K extends string
    ? { [key in K]: 'test' }
    : K;

type Obj = Test<'keyA' | 'keyB'>;

/**
 * No errors here...
 */
const obj: Obj = {
    keyA: 'test',
    keyB: 'test',
}

/**
 * Here, Typescript reports the following error:
 * Property 'keyA' does not exist on type '{ keyA: "test"; } | { keyB: "test"; }'.
 * Property 'keyA' does not exist on type '{ keyB: "test"; }'.
 */
const fn = (obj: Test<'keyA' | 'keyB'>) => {
    return obj.keyA;
}
```

Comment: It only works in the variable assignment because excess properties are allowed.

Comment: Were you looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ3dAm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, When conditional types act on a generic type, they become *distributive* when given a union type.

***For Ex:***

Consider the following,

```
type Test<K extends string | {}> = K extends string
  ? { [key in K]: "test" }
  : K;
```

and the part of your function expression

```
obj: Test<"keyA" | "keyB">
```

Here, what happens is that `obj` distributes on `"keyA" | "KeyB"` and maps over each member type of the the union, to what is effectively:

```
Test<"KeyA"> | Test<"KeyB">
```

which leaves us with:

```
{
  keyA: "test";
} | {
  keyB: "test";
}
```

The inferred type of `obj` in the function args would be something like this :

```
obj: {
  keyA: "test";
} | {
  keyB: "test";
}
```

which is why the error is *obvious*, and to achieve your goal, we need to ***avoid*** that distributivity behaviour. *For that,you can surround each side of the extends keyword with square brackets.*

```
type Test<K extends string | {}> = [K] extends [string]
  ? { [key in K]: "test" }
  : K;
```

so, TS will infer the type of `obj` as:

```
obj: {
  keyA: "test";
  keyB: "test";
}
```

which will make the following code work.

```
const fn = (obj: Test<"keyA" | "keyB">) => {
  return obj.keyA; //ok, can be accessed
};
```

Hope, it helps✌